# Read part of a website by limiting bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, pycurl, urllib3

I am trying to read several websites, get the information that I need, and then move on. Though the python code hangs on some websites. I've noticed in real browsers that at random times, the website fails to completely load, maybe its waiting on some ads to load...?

The information that I need is within the first 50kb of the website. If I use a timeout, the entire response from the connection is lost in all of the modules that I have tried (urllib, urlib3, and pycurl). Also, in pycurl, set option RANGE does not seem do anything for the url.

Does anyone know how to save the content already received upon calling a timeout. Or, does someone know how to effectively limit the content to a certain number of bytes?

Comment: Usually delays occur on websites with lots of ads. Like this one;  https://www.yahoo.com/news/

Comment: 50kb sounds high for the estimate of the datum's location. The number was gotten by save the decoded text of the website and then deleting anything after the desired location and looking at the file size. The point is, the information come early in the transfer.

Comment: You can try `requests` with `stream=True` and read the first 50kb

Comment: thanks for your help! Since I was in the process of making pycurl work, I started looking for ways to force it to stream. It lead to another solution.

Comment: If you succeeded, you can post your solution as an answer and accept it

Comment: I'm not "good enough" to accept an answer. Though, the post below worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that pycurl will still write to the buffer until the timeout. If a timeout occurs, the error can be caught and the buffer retrieved. Here is the code that I used.

```
    try:
        buffer = BytesIO()
        http_curl = pycurl.Curl()
        http_curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
        http_curl.setopt(http_curl.WRITEDATA, buffer)
        http_curl.setopt(http_curl.FOLLOWLOCATION, True)
        http_curl.setopt(http_curl.TIMEOUT_MS, 1000)
        http_curl.perform()
        http_curl.close()
    except pycurl.error:
        response = buffer.getvalue()
        response = response.decode('utf-8')
        print(response)
        pass
```

The page was partially downloaded and then printed. 
Thanks to t.m.adam for stimulating a work around.